# DOCKER: Executing one-time commands in container after docker run

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I am running into a problem with regards to my Dockerfile -- I have a container which contains a web app. Of course, when I start the container, the web app starts and by setting my **ENTRYPOINT** to **'/sbin/init'**, I can have the container running forever (as in, it doesn't just start up and shutdown).

now, the issue is, I need to *do some NFS mounts 'after' the container is started up first time*.

I understand I can remove the **ENTRYPOINT** and  utilize **CMD** to pass in lets say *CMD ./my_create_mount_script.sh*

but then, how do I make sure my container will keep running just like it was when I was using ENTRYPOINT /sbin/init?

e.g.,

if my 2nd last line in Dockerfile is: 
**CMD ./my_create_mount_script.sh** (inside the script are just some mount statements)  and my last line is: **ENTRYPOINT /sbin/init**  it won't do me any good as far as I understand because in this case, ENTRYPOINT is expecting CMD to pass it args, nothing else.

^ if it matters, I will deploying this container to AWS ECS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass multiple CMD arguments such as:

```
CMD /sbin/init ; /do_something_else
```

Or you could create a script which does all you want including the starting of the web app and then pass that to your ***ENTRYPOINT***

Comment: that CMD example you gave doesn't seem to work - it seems to only execute the secondary part (after the semicolon). Also, if I create a simple .sh file and just put in /sbin/init in it and try to pass that file to ENTRYPOINT, the /sbin/init (or just init) doesn't get executed.

Comment: @AliKhan  Have a look at this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/ and this: http://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/

Comment: thank you. The links you provided are very helpful and I was able to clear my misconceptions. As for my use case, I ended up using supervisord to start the web app as process # 2 and the script I wanted to run as process # 1.

Comment: @AliKhan you're welcome :) and i'm glad i could help